# Odd behavior with multiple class names on an element?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following CSS:

```
   .side-study-box {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    border: 3px solid #0072A6;
    text-align: center;
    height: 220px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    display: table;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #888888;
    -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #888888;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #888888;
}
    .side-study-box p {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        margin: auto;
        font-size: 24px;
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
```

And the following HTML:

```
<div class="side-study-box span6 ">
     <p>SIDE 1</p>
</div>
```

However the text isn't being centered vertically or horizontally.  If I either remove the span6 class from the div or target the span6 as opposed to side-study-box in my css, it works.  I do need both classes though... what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The element you want to centre must be nested within a display:table-cell; element, for one.

Comment: Sounds to me like another rule which is targeting `span6` is affecting things.

Comment: @cpf - I just nested it and it didn't work.  It does work if I pick one class or the other.

Comment: @Richard - any idea how I can force my styles over bootstrap's "span6"?

Comment: @JakeP - Increase the specificity? Add an `#id` selector, or prefix them with `body`: `body .side-study-box {...}` and `body .side-study-box p {...}`

Comment: @Richard: Go ahead and post that as an answer so Jake can mark it accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds to me like another rule which is targeting the `span6` class name is affecting things. Try increasing the specificity. Add an `#id` selector, or prefix them with `body`. Something like:

```
body .side-study-box { /*...*/ }
body .side-study-box p {/*...*/ }
```